# Avoid message to stdout/sterr when QProcess aborted

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

My C++ app launches a QProcess, and after 60 seconds kills the process (if it runs too long).  So that part is fine, but on the console I see:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("myapp") is still running.
```

when the QProcess is killed.  Is there some way to suppress this message?  This isn't an error requiring notification of the user.

Comment: Implement the appropriate code in your process to perform an orderly termination, when so externally signalled. Perhaps use a socket for that, or something similar. Alternatively installed a signal handler for `SIGTERM` that does an immediate `_exit(0)`, or, perhaps, redirect its standard error to `/dev/null`.

Comment: The 'myapp' is written by a third party - so I can't change how it acts.

Comment: But you can redirect its standard error to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Is the child process generating that output, or is your program?

Comment: I think my process, which creates the QProcess object, is generating the output.  Something in the Qt library (which implements QProcess) is doing this.  I don't want it too - the folks at Qt must think this is a good thing.  And just to be clear, my program captures stdout and stderr, so the Qt library is writing this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that message comes from [`QProcess`'s destructor](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp#L1256) if the child process is still running when the `QProcess` object is destroyed.  The solution is therefore to kill the child process before destroying the `QProcess` object.